# discord.js. Cant get channel id from user texting

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I've tried to make a bot join the voice channel im in and then let it send a message afterwards. Problem is I'm not completely sure I am using `voiceChannel.join()` the correct way as I get an error of `"Cannot ready property "join" of undefined"`:

```
client.on('message', msg=>{
if(msg.content === "testing"){
const channel = msg.member.voiceChannel;
channel.join() //voiceChannel.join()
        .then(msg.channel.send("!p https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-IWRmpefzE"));
    }
})
```

with that i get this error:

```
C:\Users\Jakob\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:13

channel.join();

^



TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jakob\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:13:17)
```

The bot reads the message and then I am not entirely sure what goes wrong when trying to join...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change in Discord.js v12.
Replace `msg.member.voiceChannel` with `msg.member.voice.channel`